# How to add a duration field that should consist of hours and minutes

Tags: oracle-jet

I need to add a duration field that should consist of hours and minutes. We can use  But it will get upto 23:59 I need to choose more. Is that possible?

Tried using  oj-input-time but there is limitation in entering values. I need to add more values can't use text field.